# print json object in ajax response

Tags: jquery, json

I am using ajax to submit form and print response code.

This is php response array

```
$response['code'] = 401;
$response['message'] = 'Thank You';
$response['class'] = 'alert-success';
echo json_encode($response);
```

and this is ajax code

```
$.ajax({
  dataType: 'json',
  type: 'POST',
  url: '/sellers/php-page',
  data: dataString,
  cache: false,
  success: function(d) {
     console.log(d);
  }
});
```

output of `console.log(d)` gives

```
Object { code: 401, message: "Thank You", class: "alert-success" }
```

Now I have to print only message. How could I print/use single object out of array object ?

Comment: inside success: function(d) {
     // d.message holds your message which u can bind to your div or other control
  }

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
  success: function(d) {
     console.log(d.message);   // "Thank You"
  }
```